# Curl to download and upload same file simultaneously

Tags: linux, http, bash, curl, ftp

Not sure if it's possible but I've been trying to use curl to essentially download a file from a HTTP location and output it onto an FTP server. I would really like some help if this is in fact possible.

Comment: Use one instance of curl to download, pipe the output directly into another instance which is handling the upload.

Comment: @Anon - You should make that an answer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
curl http://example.com/down | curl -T - ftp://mysite.org/up
```

By default curl spits its output to stdout - we then pipe that into another instance of curl.

On the second instance, `-T` tells curl to upload a file, and the `-` tells it to take the file data from stdin (rather than from a file on disk).

Comment: Thanks so much, that's exactly what I wanted to do!

Answer (score -1):

use multi curl to add simple curl instances. Running multi you call two requests at same time. Maybe you need to be sure that the upload starts firstly